# Azure bot sample - python - 18.bot-authentication can't run

Tags: python, botframework, emoji

Using the [official sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/18.bot-authentication) and follow the steps to run the app.

1. download the code and open it with visual studio code
2. in the terminal execute command `pip install -r requirements.txt`, then modify `config.py`, then run the app by `python app.py`

Then it may appear error like `ImportError: cannot import name 'UNICODE_EMOJI' from 'emoji' (xxxxx\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\emoji\__init__.py)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the sample `README.md` it doesn't mention this error.

It's due to the newest version of `emoji v2.0.0`, because there's no `UNICODE_EMOJI` in this version. Here's a [known issue](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji/issues/221#issuecomment-1199857533).

> try to use EMOJI_DATA as a replacement for UNICODE_EMOJI

Then in this case, going to the `utilities.py` file, replacing all `UNICODE_EMOJI` with `EMOJI_DATA`

[image]